# Implicit vs. Explicit .NET Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asyncsocket

So as I'm looking over my socket server solution in Task Manager, I notice that the application is creating and destroying Threads (9 to 10 to 15 back to 10). Some of these could be used by the MySQL Connector, but it seems that logging into the server will create a new thread.

I'm using asynchronous sockets to accept a connection, pass it to the PacketHandler instance, allthewhile listening for simultaneous connections. My question is, how do I tell what code will create a new thread? I never explicitly wrote that a thread needed to be created, but it seems to be a consequence of using asynchronous sockets. I know you're supposed to be conservative when creating threads (Cores * 2 = target # of threads) but its a hard task when you don't know what code will create a new thread by nature.

Comment: Don't worry about code that's not yours.  It's going to work the way it works; you have no control over it.  If it's really an issue, then find another third-party library.

Comment: But this is my code..

Comment: What I mean is the code you wrote.  Are you explicitly using threads?  I don't mean code that you're using like framework code or third-party code.

Comment: I'm not using any framework or third-party code, and I'm not explicitly using threads. I'm simply using the BeginAccept and EndAccept code, along with their friends Begin/EndSend, Begin/EndReceive :P

Comment: If you're using C# then you're using the framework.  It will use threads as it sees fit, with our without your knowledge.  And who cares?  Just trust that it's doing so the most efficient way it can.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Fuselight MySQL connector doesn't have real asynchronous methods. Its `Async` methods just run the sync methods inside a `Task.Run`. The issue is still open as Oracle doesn't intend to solve it. Check [this project instead](https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector) that uses real asynchronous operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properly asynchronous code only uses threads for callbacks, which usually only needs thread-pool threads, and unless you're doing something wrong, there's no need to spin up new thread-pool threads.

This is certainly the case with the current implementation of Sockets in MS.NET. They register a callback on an asynchronous event, and a threadpool thread is used for the duration of that callback. Unless you're doing synchronous I/O operations in the callback, there's no point in creating any more threads on the threadpool.

Don't look in the task manager - look in the debugger. It might very well be that the threads you are seeing have nothing to do with the library you're using. There's quite a few infrastructure threads in .NET that are created and disposed of - notably, the garbage collector. Check the stack traces on those threads, and you'll know what they do.

**EDIT**: 
And in this case, it seems that the MySQL Connector indeed doesn't use asynchronous I/O. It's only pretending a synchronous I/O to be asynchronous using multi-threading - in other words, the asynchronous API is completely useless bollocks :) And since they are using threadpool threads for synchronous I/O, you're going to get plenty of problems with that. Either use a different library, or avoid the asynchronous API - it's lying to you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot! Still new to understanding threads and I'm just very curious about how these are used in applications similar to mine.

Comment: @Fuselight If you're doing everything 100% right, you never need more threads than how many the CPU can execute simultaneously. In most applications, there's usually more threads for various reasons, though - simplicity, isolation, interop, control... Synchronous I/O is somewhat easier to use, especially without advanced language features like `await`. The whole area of multi-threading and asynchronous code is rather complex, and not exactly trivial to get right - you really want to pick a book on the subject if you want to do anything substantial.

Comment: @Luaan the OP is asking about MySQL Connector which fakes async operations with `Task.Run`. [This alternative project](https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector) offers true async operations *and* runs on .NET Core, tested on Ubuntu

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Which makes it "not properly asynchronous", which is why I suggested the OP uses a debugger to see what really happens. I only targeted proper async APIs, including the Socket API Fuselight mentioned. But I'll include that in the answer, thanks :)

Comment: I actually wasn't asking about the MySQL connector, really, but thanks for the tip. For now I've used synchronous database operations since they aren't intense.

Comment: @FuseLight with other databases, using the `async` version is as easy as using the sync ones. The difference does matter because async alows you to use a *smaller* VM instance for the same amount of traffic.

Comment: @Luaan the task manager *can* show the difference between sync and async because blocking waits typically start with spinlocks. A web server may end up burning cycles doing nothing to the point of metldown (don't ask how I know)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, MySQL Connector doesn't offer true asynchronous methods. Its `Begin/End` methods fake asynchronous execution by [wrapping the synchronous version](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/6.9/Source/MySql.Data/command.cs#L710) in a thread:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

{

  if (caller != null)

    Throw(new MySqlException(Resources.UnableToStartSecondAsyncOp));



  caller = new AsyncDelegate(AsyncExecuteWrapper);

  asyncResult = caller.BeginInvoke(1, behavior, null, null);

  return asyncResult;

}
```

where [AsyncExecuteWrapper](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/6.9/Source/MySql.Data/command.cs#L669) is :

```
internal object AsyncExecuteWrapper(int type, CommandBehavior behavior)

{

  thrownException = null;

  try

  {

    if (type == 1)

      return ExecuteReader(behavior);

    return ExecuteNonQuery();

  }

  catch (Exception ex)

  {

    thrownException = ex;

  }

  return null;

}
```

As a result, they waste a thread waiting for a response. A bug was filed three years ago [but never got a real answer](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111)

That's why this alternative [MySQLConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/) project was created that provides true asynchronous operations as  well as .NET Core support,eg [this method](https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector/blob/master/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlClient/MySqlCommand.cs#L111)

```
    internal async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var reader = (MySqlDataReader) await ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.Default, ioBehavior, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            do
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync(ioBehavior, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                }
            } while (await reader.NextResultAsync(ioBehavior, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false));
            return reader.RecordsAffected;
        }
    }
```

You'll see that [ReadAsync](https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector/blob/master/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlClient/MySqlDataReader.cs#L48) is also a proper asynchronous method

The difference is significant, especially in web applications, as it allows you to use a *smaller* VM instance to server the same traffic. Or the same VM can server more traffic. In any case, the pricing difference is real.

This happens because asynchronous network operations are actually offloaded to the driver or host. A thread from the IO thread pool is only used when the network driver delivers a response to the application. In the case of paravirtualization, offloading can go all the way to the host.

Faked synchronous operations on the other hand block and may even result in busy waiting. That's because synchronization primitives are meant to be used for ... *synchronizing access* to shared resources. Suspending the thread costs, so awaiting on a primitive first starts with a Spinlock and only suspends the thread after a certain time passes.

This is why web applications that don't take asynchrony into consideration can end up burning a lot of CPU while waiting for remote responses